# Setting a new page with wp_insert_post as start page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating an APP with a Wordpress child theme. It has a start page created with `wp_insert_post` when activating the theme. How do I set this page as `startpage` with PHP in **functions.php**?

```
// Install theme
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == 'themes.php' ) {
        $last_id = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_title' => 'Welcome to this wonderful page!',
            'post_content' => 'Holy smoke',
            'post_name' => 'startpage',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'comment_status' => 'closed'
        ));
        update_post_meta($last_id, "_wp_page_template", "page.php");

// Set this page as startpage... but how? 

} // Install theme
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If understood correctly, you are searching for the option `page_on_front`:

> [image: page on front]

Just use:

```
// Set "static page" as the option
update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );

// Set the front page ID
update_option( 'page_on_front', $last_id );
```